# Is there a .Net.Standard alternative to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need the wildcard functionality of the script and link tags in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` to load my angular bundles with hashes, in a large **.NET standard** MVC 5.2 application, as described in this article:

http://michaco.net/blog/Angular4GettingHashedWebpackBundlesWorkingInASPNETCoreMVC

which is for .Net Core. But converting to Core is not an option because of the scale of the application.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: "But converting to Core is not an option because of the scale of the application" what do you mean ? Shouldn't anything built on top of .NET Standard be able to run on .NET Core ? How does the scale of the app change anything ?

Comment: Well, i mean that its an existing ASP.NET MVC 5.2 app. Which is not the Core framework.
It would take a lot of work to upgrade it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1